# new ZFS setup mirror vs raid with multiple disks on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, zfs

I am new to ZFS and have been doing lot of research.  I'm ready to switch from hardware RAID to ZFS. Here is the list of drives I have:

- 3 1.5TB drives
- 6 2TB drives
- 6 4TB drives

My primary goal is to set up a home system with fast read access by multiple (1-6) users.

option 1: less usable space but faster?

```
pool data
  vdev1 mirror
    2 2TB disks
  vdev2 mirror
    2 2TB disks
  vdev3 mirror
    2 2TB disks
  vdev4 mirror
    2 4TB disks
  vdev5 mirror
    2 4TB disks
  vdev6 mirror
    2 4TB disks
```

option 2: (this is close to what I have now)

```
pool
  vdev1
    6 2TB drives as RAID6
  vdev2
    6 4TB drives as RAID6
maybe???
  vdev3 striped
    3 1.5TB disks
```

These would just hold copy of data I want fast access to. From what I read if you have over 5 disks in vdev performance degrades. Is there another combination that might be better to achieve what I am trying to do?

I also have one 120GB SSD drive to use for caching or as drive for logs? Or maybe for both if I split it up and use different partitions as vdev?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration you should use totally depends on your use case. For a home setup (no VMs, no databases, etc.), you probably won't be able to tell the difference in latency/throughput performance for anything except maybe how you use the SSD, so personally I would use RAID-Z for the extra storage capacity.

That said, these are the main tradeoffs between RAID-Z and mirroring for the HDD disks in the pool:

- Space used for parity information. Mirroring results in 100% data overhead and RAID-Z will be much less than that, with one or more parity blocks per group of data blocks. There are various RAID-Z options you can use that will make this higher or lower -- see [this blog post from one of the creators of ZFS](https://www.delphix.com/blog/delphix-engineering/zfs-raidz-stripe-width-or-how-i-learned-stop-worrying-and-love-raidz) for more detailed information.
- Redundancy. `raidz1` can survive the failure of one disk, but you can use `raidz2`+ to survive multiple failures. With mirroring you can in theory lose half the pool, but worst case losing just 2 drives could wipe out a lot of data.
- Performance characteristics: latency, throughput, resilver time after a disk failure, and performance during a resilver will all be different depending on your pool configuration. (If you don't have strict requirements on any of these I wouldn't worry too much about it though. Resilvers and performance during resilvers are the things that will be most different, and those are fairly rare events anyway.)

For how to use the SSD, probably splitting it up is the best choice for most use cases:

- If sync write latency is important, you should configure a SLOG device. You probably won't need more than a few GiB for this, since the data written there is flushed to the main pool very quickly.
- If you need read latency to be really good, you should configure an L2ARC device. Since your SSD is so small compared to the overall pool, you will need to have a working set that will fit on the SSD to get the largest boost from this.